# Errors in Azure DevOps build - are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using **VSTS** (*Azure DevOps*) for the first time and am setting up my first build (I have previously been using TFS). I'm trying to build a .NET application targeting *.NET Framework 4.6*.

However I'm getting build errors relating to missing namespaces and / or assemblies.

*Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OwinStartupAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

*Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

*Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

The issues all seem to be related i.e. the nuget packages aren't getting restored during the build process.

I've therefore added a **Nuget restore** task to the pipeline before my build step.

[image]

And have checked the option **Restore Nuget packages** on the build step.

[image]

Comment: ...and what happens when you run the build with the `NuGet Restore` task present?

Comment: I get the errors mentioned in my post above.

Comment: Do you get errors during the NuGet restore step?

Comment: I don't get any errors in the Nuget restore.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Anyone else know how to solved ? In My case It's a dll that references a lot of external dll from other projects.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get this working as I had some of the Nuget packages checked-in as part of source-control. I removed the entire packages folder from the solution and this has resolved the issue. There must have been some conflict between the packages I had in source-control and the packages I was trying to restore.

Answer (score 5):

I had some projects in a large solution with this problem; they had the old "packages.config" files. To fix, In Solution Explorer, right-click on a packages.config file and select Migrate packages.config to PackageReference.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference).

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this would happen because, for some reason, the local cache was only partially populated. Disabling the local cache in the build definition fixed the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the repository cannot create/receive the *.config files because my .gitignore avoid the upload from user, and without this files the build has no reference about to do. I created the files directly on repository