# Error at executing Azure Pipeline for a .Net Desktop App - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm creating my first Pipeline to build a .NET Desktop application. I have added the needed task to my YML file but I'm getting the following error, regarding an assembly that may be missing or not found.

Error Message: "The type or namespace name 'AxAcroPDFLibre' could not be found..."

[image]

This is the complete code of my YML file:

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
     
- task: CopyFiles@2    
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'    
  inputs:    
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'    
    Contents: '**/bin/**'    
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'    
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
       
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1    
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'    
  inputs:    
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'    
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

I found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52383814/4459694) here on StackOverflow, but I have checked my nugget package command and I have it in the build file.

At the end of the process, the job fails.

[image]

Right now that's all I've tried since I'm documenting myself on Azure DevOps Pipelines. If you have any recommendations I will appreciate them.

Comment: This issue is not related to the azure pipelines, check your project how you are referencing this AxAcroPDFLibre, right click on the dependency and in properties check if the 'output: copy always is checked', what I see is that the reference is not being copied/restored, therefore the build job can't find it. My recommendation is delete the binaries of your project in your local machine and try to build it in release mode.

Comment: @Bruno I tried to follow your instructions but couldn't find that property in my reference. I will take a look into building the app in Release mode. Thanks for your suggestions.